# How to store ICollection value into database in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Business model, which simply inherits from ApplicationUser, and inside it I have a field defined like this:

```
public class Business : ApplicationUser
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then, I have created a view model for this specific model, and it also includes the above line, so it has this:

```
public class BusinessViewModel
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then, in my view, I have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subcategories, "Subcategory", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <span id="subcats">

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, I'm populating the subcategories through an AJAX call, according to which category is previously selected. My JS part looks like this:

```
$("#CategoryID").change(function () {
    $("#subcats").empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Account/GetSubcategories',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: $("#CategoryID").val() },
        success: function (subcategories) {
            $.each(subcategories, function (i, subcategory) {
                $("#subcats").append('<input type="checkbox" name="' + subcategory.value + '" value="' + subcategory.id + '" />' + subcategory.value + '<br />');
            });
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            console.log('Failed to retrieve subcategories! ' + ex);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

So, the point is that when the form is filled, and the user clicks the button a new business user is registered inside the AspNetUsers, it was working all fine, when I had a single Subcategory field for a Business, but now I changed my logic and I accept a collection of Subcategories for a Business. And I don't know how to store it now in the database, I have something like this, but as you can notice I am not storing the subcategories. How can I also store the subcategories?

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> RegisterBusiness(BusinessViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new Business { BusinessName = model.BusinessName, BusinessAddress = model.BusinessAddress, CategoryID = model.CategoryID,
            BusinessZip = model.BusinessZip, BusinessPhone = model.BusinessPhone, BusinessDescription = model.BusinessDescription, Facebook = model.Facebook, Twitter = model.Twitter, UserName = model.BusinessName, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            ...
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    ...
}
```

How can I also get the subcategories that were checked and then store them in the database as a collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
foreach(var subcategory in model.Subcategories)
{
    db.Entry(subcategory).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    user.Subcategories.Add(subcategory);
}
```

Where `db` is your `ApplicationDbContext`. Basically this loops through all the subcategories in the model, marks them as unchanged in terms of the entity state (so the framework won't try to add them as new to the database), and then adding the subcategory to the user's collection.

Comment: I get that the above code only checks not to add new subcategories, but how will I synchronize them with the business? As you can see above, I create a new business object and simply assign all the fields to the once I got from the model, but how will I assign the subcategory to business? Because it is a collection not a single object? That's my problem.

Comment: Your code looks to be fine as it is. All you need to do is loop through subcategories and add them to the business collection as I've shown above. 1) Instantiate business class. 2) Add subcategories as I shown. 3) Use `CreateAsync` to create the business.

Comment: Got it, so you mean I need to insert your code above between my `var user ...` and `var result...` lines. Right?